# Can someone help me resolve an sql syntax error on pgadmin while creating a function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-functions, pgadmin, create-function

First Attempt -

```
CREATE FUNCTION rental_quarter (rental_date TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS VARCHAR(7)
BEGIN 
 IF MONTH(rental_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN RETURN YEAR(rental_date)+ ”Q1”;
 ELSE IF MONTH(rental_date) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN RETURN YEAR(rental_date)+ ”Q2” ; 
 ELSE IF MONTH(rental_date) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN RETURN YEAR(rental_date)+ ”Q3”;
 ELSE IF MONTH(rental_date) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN RETURN YEAR(rental_date)+ ”Q4”;
 ELSE RETURN NULL ;
END IF;
END;
```

Latest try [Code and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw3xX.png)

[EDIT Suggested fix error #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdodW.png)

I am new to sql and have been stuck on this a few hours . I am trying to create a rental_quarter(rental_date) function that turns the time stamped date format (without timezone) into year + quarter. I have no Idea what I am doing wrong. I have tried using AS, DECLARE, SET AS. I've done every variation of semicolons. It has to be a user defined function to meet project requirements. Please help.

Comment: 1) The code shown above and the one in the picture is difference. 2) Post all text here as text, not as links to images.

Comment: Documentation is your friend: 1) [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html)  2) Anonymous function [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html)

Comment: I clearly stated they were my starting attempt and ending attempt.

Comment: To repeat  comment from @deceze  **DO NOT** post textual information as images. Copy and paste as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a function for this, to_char(), you don't have write one yourself:

```
SELECT to_char('2023-08-01'::timestamp, 'YYYY"Q"Q');
```

Result: 2023Q3

Answer (score -1):

This is with minimum changes I think:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rental_quarter (rental_date TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS VARCHAR(7) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 
 IF MONTH(rental_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN RETURN YEAR(rental_date)+ ”Q1”;
 ELSIF MONTH(rental_date) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN RETURN YEAR(rental_date)+ ”Q2”;  
 ELSIF MONTH(rental_date) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN RETURN YEAR(rental_date)+ ”Q3”;
 ELSIF MONTH(rental_date) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN RETURN YEAR(rental_date)+ ”Q4”;
 ELSE RETURN NULL ;
 END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help! I still got an error. I updated the question with a picture of what it says. Do you have any other ideas by chance?

Comment: seems fine to me https://dbfiddle.uk/84uQbflW

Comment: This is an incomplete answer as it leaves out essential parts of the code.

Comment: @KB_Wonderland, again read the docs [plgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html).

Comment: Sorry - The formatting deleted the first line of code.